# Database pattern with two types of owners for an object. Like how users and groups can make posts in FB

Tags: database-design, schema, relations

Please help. There is a problem I have tried to resolve for some time now. I want to come up with a pattern where i have a table with advertisements on a web platform. These advertisements shall be owned either by individual users (accounts) or by an entity which represents a group of users (accounts) the members of which have permissions on the advertisement. There shall also be a manager of the advertisement. When the advertisement is owned by a group, the accounts dont matter and the info for the group shall be displayed. My problem is that I always come with anti patterns for this schema. Can you suggest me something?
 Your help will be highly appreciated.